# Does Slack app support Multi Select dropdown in their message menus?

Tags: multi-select, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I'm creating a Slack app, where I want to provide Multi Select dropdowns for the Users to select. But, I don't see any documentation for Multi Select on https://api.slack.com/. If it is not available, is there a workaround for it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems now its possible... 
Check the block kit:

[image]

```
    {
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Pick one or more items from the list"
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "multi_static_select",
                "placeholder": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Select an item",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "options": [
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Choice 1",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-0"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Choice 2",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-1"
                    }
                ],
                 "action_id": "create_feedback_final_step"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Use this block with **action_id** for getting all the inputs that the user selected!

Answer (score 1):

No.

Slack does not support multi select drop downs. As workaround you can place multiple drop-downs on one page. This works best with Dialogs, since a normal interactive message will only accept one input (and you need a loop to query multiple inputs). But a Dialog will allow for up to 5 inputs to be selected together.

Comment: Thanks @Erik. Though, this doesn't solve my problem completely, I can use this as a work around for few of my cases. But I feel Slack should be supporting Multi Select as it is one of the basic needs for any forms.